# Source script to separate environment in R, not the global environment

Tags: r, r-environment

Is there a way to `source()` a script in **R** such that it is attached as a parent to the global environment (`.GlobalEnv`)?

Currently, when I source a script, all variables and functions of that script appear in my global (interactive) environment. I'd like to include these variables and functions in the search path, but not in `.GlobalEnv`. That is, I'd like the sourced script to behave like an attached package, which gets attached between the global and base environments (see figure from [***Advanced R*** *Environments*](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html))

[image]

Comment: Just build a package?

Comment: I would like to avoid building a package in this particular instance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following environment insertion appears to achieve the desired functionality:

Check the current search path:

```
search()
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics"
# [4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets"
# [7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Add new environment for sourced packages and use `local` parameter when `source()`ing:

```
myEnv <- new.env()    
source("some_other_script.R", local=myEnv)
attach(myEnv, name="sourced_scripts")
```

Check the search path:

```
search()
#  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "sourced_scripts"   "package:dplyr"
#  [4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
#  [7] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"
# [10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Note that we `attach()` the new environment *after* sourcing, so that `dplyr` is attached after our script environment in the search path.

Answer (score 11):

I would also like to a solution using [**`sys.source`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/sys.source) function. Using `envir` and `toplevel.env` arguments allows for convenient (IMHO) bypassing of the global environment. As per the linked documentation:

> `sys.source` [p]arses expressions in the given file, and then
>   successively evaluates them in the specified environment.

```
tstEnv <- new.env()
sys.source(file = "tst.R", envir = tstEnv, toplevel.env = tstEnv)
```

where **`tst.R`** contains:

```
a <- 1
b <- 1
```

## Results:

```
ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)
# [1] "tstEnv"
ls(envir = tstEnv)
# [1] "a" "b"
tstEnv$a
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to source a script as if it was a package (i.e. such that [lexical scoping](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping) won't result in the use of variables defined in the global environment when calling functions defined in your R script) is to create an environment that that is whose parent is the `.BaseNamespaceEnv`, and then call `source()` using that environment.

For example if you have a script like this:

```r
# << my-script.R >>
my_fun <- function(x){x + y}
```

Then evaluating the following at the console, won't generate an error, as it would if `my_fun` were defined within it's own package:

```
source("my-script.R")
y = 2
my_fun(1)
#> 3
```

However, if you create an environment whose `search()` path does not include the Global Environment (`.GlobalEnv`) then you'll get a proper error when you call the function from your script:

```
# Create the environment:
ENV = new.env(parent = .BaseNamespaceEnv)
# Attache it to the search path so that objects in your environment can be
# found from the global environment (i.e. from the console):
attach(ENV)
# do things:
source("my-script.R",ENV)
y = 2
my_fun(1)
#> Error in .ENV$my_fun(3) : object 'y' not found
```

Comment: Good answer (I am looking for a solution too), but functions of packages loaded in the sourced file with `library` are still not accessible because they are attached as parent of the environment `ENV` in the search path. Try this code `library(data.table); print(search()); x <- as.data.table(mtcars)` in the "my-script.R" and you will get the error "Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'cyl' not found" when sourced as you described it. The reason is the "wrong" search path within the sourced file: `[1] ".GlobalEnv" "package:data.table" "ENV" ...`

Comment: Actually, you would never call `library()` from within an R package.  You would list the packages that *your* package depends on in the `imports` section of the `DESCRIPTION` file and R would take care to load those packages before loading your package.  The equivalent here would be to call `library(data.table)` and then use `ENV = new.env(parent = as.environment("package:data.table"))`.

Comment: Yes your are absolutely right, no `library` within a package. The reason why I am looking for a solution is "batch job framework package" I am developing and that sources external code that does the real work and the sourced external code shall be isolated as much as possible in an environment. I only inject the "job context" data and the sourced code does not even know more than the "job context" interface from the framework. I know I could also define function interface that must be implemented but I want make it as easy as possible for the users...

Comment: It feels like you're reinventing the wheel as there is already a mechanism for running batches of R scripts (i.e. `help("Rscript")`), and IMHO, R is a terrible language for running code in isolation.   I'd personally go for scripting R sessions from another language Python, NodeJS, Powershell, or Bash, or whatever language you like that is good at managing sub-processes.

Comment: In case it's helpful, [I used this code](https://github.com/jdthorpe/Rmisc/blob/master/R/sandbox.R) for running my own code in isolation a while back, where `sandbox()` is just a weak wrapper around `source()`

Comment: Then again, maybe you're looking for something as simple as using `ENV = new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 5):

From the `source` documentation, the `local` argument can be an environment which determines where the sourced expressions are evaluated.

This suggests that you could create a new environment, run `source` passing this environment to `local`, then `attach` the environment to the search path.

Or you can use attach with `what=NULL` to create an empty environment, save the return value, and pass that to `local` in `source`:

```
tmp <- attach(what=NULL)
source('test.R', local=tmp)
```

or as a single line:

```
source('test.R', local=attach(NULL))
```

Comment: An issue with this method is that the sourced script environment is inserted and any libraries attached within the scripts are children - so it can't find the libraries

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my answer is any different from the answers given above, but I use the following code:

```
if (!exists('.env')) .env <- new.env() # creates an environment in which to store functions
if ('.env' %in% search()) detach(.env) # detaches .env if it already exists; does not "erase" functions previously stored in .env
func <- "filenameWhereSourceCodeIsStored"
source(paste0("C:/Users/JT/R/Functions/", func, ".R"), .env)
attach(.env)
```