# Get object names from a .R file

Tags: r

I can get obj_name list from the environment, but how to get obj_name from a .r file?

I tried ls but is only get obj_name from the environment, but I need get from R file, eg:

```
# filename test.R
func_1=function(){...}
func_2=function(){...}
func_3=function(){...}
c_1=R6Class()
#page end
```

I want to get `test.R`'s obj list name.
Like this:

```
"func_1","func_2","func_3","c_1"
```

Comment: Good question, you can `source` `.R` file to a new environment and get object names from there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620669/source-script-to-separate-environment-in-r-not-the-global-environment

Comment: @PoGibas I guess OP wants to retrieve the objects without sourcing the file

Comment: thanks a lot , your answer slove my question briefly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for @PoGibas's solution.
that's what i want

```
my_env=new.env()
source("myfile.R",local=my_env)
ls(my_env)
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like an xy-problem. Anyway, you can parse the file and extract the first arguments of top-level calls to `<-` and `=`:

```
na.omit(
  sapply(
    as.list(
      parse(text = 
      "# filename test.R
       func_1=function(){...}
       func_2=function(){...}
       func_3=function(){...}
       c_1=R6Class()
       #page end")), 
    function(x) if (as.character(x[[1]]) %in% c("<-", "=")) as.character(x[[2]]) else NA))
#[1] "func_1" "func_2" "func_3" "c_1"
```

I'm assuming you don't use `assign` or more exotic forms of assignment. If you need assignments nested in other functions (such as `if` or `for`), you'll need to write a recursive function that crawls the parse tree.

Comment: Maybe the assignment `->` can be taken into account as well?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding You'll be amazed by what `as.list(parse(text = "3 -> a"))` returns.